# Security of public S3 objects with random keys

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket containing objects that I want to share with users of a website. I know I can use something like [Query String Authentication](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/S3_QSAuth.html) to provide secure access to the objects, but what if I instead make each object publicly-readable yet "hidden" behind a complex key (i.e. URL) containing a cryptographically-strong random number? If the containing bucket disallows listing of objects, there wouldn't be a way to guess or discover the URLs, correct? Or is there some security hole I'm overlooking?

Side note: my first thought was to use UUIDs in the keys, but I read that they can apparently be predicted, given a few previous instances. That said, I don't have an understanding of how easily that can be done. If it's non-trivial, I probably wouldn't worry too much about using them instead of a strong random number...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is if the once shared URL gets into the hands of another user (say via sharing). If you ensure the URL is kept sufficiently secret, it is ok with this approach (say you return the URL to a user via https, and this user dont share it).

Any loophole here will cause a security hole - and here is where the query string based signature scheme is helpful, since the signatures are made to expire after a fixed time and so any re-sharing wont also harm you.

You can use UUIDs (ensure they dont end up duplicating, by regenerating another one if the new one collides). They are probably as difficult (or more) to guess as any other 8-letter password.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do what you want is to generate [pre-signed URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) for each of the objects you want to share. If you make them with a short lifetime, then they cannot be shared outside that time period. All of the [AWS-provided SDKs](http://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/) have support for this feature.